# How can you refine HTTP::Headers.normalize_header?

Tags: ruby, refinements

normalize_header in HTTP::headers turns underscores into dashes (https://github.com/httprb/http/issues/337).  This isn't correct in some cases.  I can easily monkey patch this.  But I was trying to figure out how to use a refinement to narrow the scope of the modification.

```
require "http"

module NormalizeHeaderPatch
  refine HTTP::Headers do
    def normalize_header(name)
      puts "refined normalize_header"
      name
    end
  end
end

using NormalizeHeaderPatch
auth_res = HTTP.headers(
  "client_id" => "client_id"
).get("https://www.google.com")
```

But that doesn't work.  My gut is that I have missed something with the refinement not being activated once we are in the scope that ends up calling normalize_header but I don't know how to arrange for that to work.